# How to get a array index that didn't come from the DB in Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have an application that receives data from some input fields and populates one table, without passing through the backend, it's a list of records to be persisted in the DB and i can mount the list with no problems.

The thing is, i need to edit or to exclude any item on this list anytime i want but, i can't do it because i can't get the index of this item on the list.

I've tried a lot ways, using a v-for inside of a col tag that's inside of a template tag (i'm using bootstrap-vue by the way) and didn't work, i try to get this index using this.*data*[index] and got undefined.

For exclude, i use this.*data*.splice(index, 1) but this aways exclude the first record on the list, which was already expected, if i take "1" out, it excludes the entire list.

Here's the code:

This is my b-table:

```
<b-table id="listTable" bordered hover striped :items="filtered" :fields="fields" small>                    
                <template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
                    <b-button variant="warning" >
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </b-button>

                    <b-button variant="danger" @click="deleteTask(data.item)" class="mr-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </b-button>
                </template>
            </b-table>
```

That's the function that populates the table, this goes to de backend and returns the data:

```
populateList(){
        this.pecaList.peca = this.peca.peca
        this.pecaList.qnt = this.peca.qnt
        this.pecaList.vlUnit = this.peca.vlUnit
        this.pecaList.vlTot = this.peca.vlUnit * this.peca.qnt
    }

createPecaList(e) {
        axios.post(this.rotalistapeca, this.pecaList)
            .then((res) => {
                this.peca.list.push(res.data)

                this.pecaList = {}
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                alert("Try again");
            });
    }
```

This is the function on the backend(Laravel):

```
public function createList(Request $request)
{
    $totValue = $request->qnt * $request->vlUnit;

    $dados = [
        'peca' => $request->peca,
        'qnt' => $request->qnt,
        'vlUnit' => $request->vlUnit,
        'vlTot' => $totValue
    ];

    if($dados){
        return response()->json($dados);
    } else {
        return ('Something went wrong');
    }
}
```

I'm new in Vue and development in general, how can i get this index after all?
If this data first goes to the backend and returns, it may be easier to use but that's not what i'm trying to do, i want to get this index without passing data to the backend.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to artificially introduce an ID attribute to each of your items, when you load them into the **data** attribute.

Something like this may be good:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pecaList: []
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          // console.log(json)

          // creating another ID, based on the current list index
          return json.map((e, i) => {
            return { ...e,
              addedId: i
            }
          })
        })
    },
    deleteThis(id) {
      this.pecaList = this.pecaList.filter(e => e.addedId !== id)
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.pecaList = await this.fetchData()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Click on the list items to delete them one by one</h3>
  <ul>
    <li :key="peca.id" v-for="peca in pecaList" @click="deleteThis(peca.addedId)">{{peca.addedId}} {{peca.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The mockup data already has an **id** attribute, so I added an ID called **addedId**. From then on this **addedId** identifies your item (regardless of its index in the table or list; until you fetch another set of data or reload, or something like that), so you can use it for deletion.

Actually it's not advised to use an items index in a list for identification - it can change (like with sorting or filtering), so whenever you want to use an ID be sure that it correctly identifies an item in all use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @muka.gergely, is really nice, but at this moment, i'll run with the list as mentioned in my answer... Thanks anyway, i'll try to apply your ideia in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of getting what i need to be done, not like i wanted but it works, only change my b-table for a b-list-group.

It ends like this:

```
<b-list-group>
                <b-list-group-item v-for="(item, index) in peca.list">
                    <strong>Item: </strong>{{ index }}
                    <strong>Peça: </strong>{{ item.peca}}
                    <strong>Quantidade: </strong>{{ item.qnt}}
                    <strong>Valor Unitário: </strong>{{ item.vlUnit }}
                    <strong>Valor total: </strong>{{ item.vlTot }}

                    <b-button variant="warning" >
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </b-button>

                    <b-button variant="danger" @click="deleteTask(index)" class="mr-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </b-button>
                </b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>
```

Working now.

Thanks all.